# How to get the maximum id values and update the data to the id?

Tags: android, realm

I am facing the issue in querying the maximum id values and also want to update the data to the maximum id .

```
  public void addDataToRealm()
    {
        int key;
        realm.beginTransaction();
        detailsModel = realm.createObject(DetailsModel.class, id);
        detailsModel.setName(name.getText().toString());
        detailsModel.setPlace(place.getText().toString());
        detailsModel.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
        realm.commitTransaction();
        id++;
}
```

In the above code i am incrementing the id value for each transaction.
Is it possible to get the maximum id values from the realm database and need to update the values for the maximum id.Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-incrementing-ids may help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // Get the current max id in the EntityName table
        Number id = realm.where(EntityName.class).max("id");
        // If id is null, set it to 1, else set increment it by 1
        int nextId = (id == null) ? 1 : id.intValue() + 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: the `max()` needs to be called in a transaction to make sure other thread won't increase it at the same time. Could you please edit your answer to put the code into a transaction?

Comment: @beeender thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this method

```
 int key;
 key = realm.where(DetailsModel.class).max("id").intValue() + 1;
```

This methods works...